# Identification of Independent and Dependent Variables

Tags: functions, terminology

I often have trouble identifying what is the dependent variable and what is the independent variable in written English.

Consider this:
Dependence of A on B. In this case it's clear A is dependent and B is independent.

But how about:
"Effect of C on D"?

And

"E dependence of F"?

It's not immediately clear what is the dependent variable and which is independent. Is there a good guide to this somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Effect of $C$ on $D$

In other words, if we know something about $C$ then this tells us something about $D$. If we know something about $D$, it doesn't tell us anything about $C$. So $D$ is dependent on $C$.

> $E$ dependence of $F$

I think this might require more context, but sounds like "dependence of $F$" is saying that the one that depends is $F$.